# Why responsive form throws such error in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I spent countless hours on a really weird issue. I have this responsive 
form:

```
<form [formGroup]="mainParametersForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="center-block">Name:
    <input class="form-control" formControlName="serviceName">
  </label>
  </div>
</form>
```

and in the component I build it like:

`this.mainParametersForm = new FormGroup({
      serviceName: new FormControl()
    });`

It works fine in dev mode. It works fine in PROD mode with aot=false but not working (page throwing error during rendering time) when enabling aot. It throws an error which is really hard to debug because all js files are minified and packed on prod:

`vendor.498a2ea9b9af14474e91.bundle.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No provider for e!
Error: No provider for e!
    at S (vendor.498a2ea9b9af14474e91.bundle.js:1)
    at x (vendor.498a2ea9b9af14474e91.bundle.js:1)
    at t._throwOrNull (vendor.498a2ea9b9af14474e91.bundle.js:1)
    at t._getByKeyDefault (vendor.498a2ea9b9af14474e91.bundle.js:1)
    at t._getByKey (vendor.498a2ea9b9af14474e91.bundle.js:1)
    at t.get (vendor.498a2ea9b9af14474e91.bundle.js:1)
    at We (vendor.498a2ea9b9af14474e91.bundle.js:1)
    at t.get (vendor.498a2ea9b9af14474e91.bundle.js:1)
    at Tn (vendor.498a2ea9b9af14474e91.bundle.js:1)
    at Sn (vendor.498a2ea9b9af14474e91.bundle.js:1)
    at S (vendor.498a2ea9b9af14474e91.bundle.js:1)
    at x (vendor.498a2ea9b9af14474e91.bundle.js:1)
    at t._throwOrNull (vendor.498a2ea9b9af14474e91.bundle.js:1)
    at t._getByKeyDefault (vendor.498a2ea9b9af14474e91.bundle.js:1)
    at t._getByKey (vendor.498a2ea9b9af14474e91.bundle.js:1)
    at t.get (vendor.498a2ea9b9af14474e91.bundle.js:1)
    at We (vendor.498a2ea9b9af14474e91.bundle.js:1)
    at t.get (vendor.498a2ea9b9af14474e91.bundle.js:1)
    at Tn (vendor.498a2ea9b9af14474e91.bundle.js:1)
    at Sn (vendor.498a2ea9b9af14474e91.bundle.js:1)
    at u (polyfills.2a1ff9952afc40674bd4.bundle.js:1)
    at u (polyfills.2a1ff9952afc40674bd4.bundle.js:1)
    at polyfills.2a1ff9952afc40674bd4.bundle.js:1
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.2a1ff9952afc40674bd4.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (vendor.498a2ea9b9af14474e91.bundle.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask (polyfills.2a1ff9952afc40674bd4.bundle.js:1)
    at r.runTask (polyfills.2a1ff9952afc40674bd4.bundle.js:1)
    at o (polyfills.2a1ff9952afc40674bd4.bundle.js:1)
    at t.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.2a1ff9952afc40674bd4.bundle.js:1)
    at h (polyfills.2a1ff9952afc40674bd4.bundle.js:1)`

I would be really glad if somebody can give a hint. My angular packages version:

  `"@angular/common": "^4.2.5",
  "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.5",
  "@angular/core": "^4.2.5",
  "@angular/forms": "^4.2.5",
  "@angular/http": "^4.2.5",`